# Wordpress rewrite url

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I have created a custom post type called `articls` using [Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) UI plugin.
Now I can access the custom post using URL like

```
https://example.com.au/articles/pot-name-1/
```

But I want access them like the below URL

```
https://example.com.au/articles/2018/01/post-name-1/
```

Comment: Did you check the permalink settings to see if the plugin overwrote them? You may just need to set a custom permalink structure like the following = /%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/

Comment: @MagRat In my case articles in a post type not a category

Comment: I came across this plugin that should allow you to set up custom permalink structure with CPT's https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date archives for custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142888/date-archives-for-custom-post-type)

Comment: @MagRa Look like https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/ give me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

But we are not limited to default formats, as WordPress allows users to customize the pretty permalink format by setting one or more structure tags.
The custom structure option allows to set a highly customized pretty permalink format
[image]
The custom structure option allows to set a highly customized pretty permalink format